# how to limit the data to be displayed from the long text area field in the visual force page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

We have developed a custome emails section through custom vf page. Need to display the sub string of text body from the email message object.
Below is the custome email section we have developed :
[image]

below is the standard email section: below subject of every email message another line displays which is a part of email textbody.
[image]
To display the subject from controller we are writing below lines in vf page

```
<apex:column headerValue="Subject">
        <a href="/{!items.id}" style="{!if(items.status == '0','cursor: pointer;font-weight: bold;','cursor: pointer;')}"
            onclick="openDetailPage('{!items.id}', '{!items.Incoming}')" >
          {!items.Subject}</a>
</apex:column>
```

trying to use `<apex:outputtext></apex:outputtext>` after `<a/>` tag to display the starting line from email message text body.  I got the idea of using the method textbody.substring(0, 5) can you give me some clue how to use this method to get the required out put.

Comment: why not use `{!LEFT(items.Subject,5)}` ?

Comment: Thanks cropredy that worked. But i need to apply this on TextBody not on subject.   below line i added that resolve my issue.                    
 <apex:outputtext style="font-family:arial;font-size:11px;color:DimGray" value="{!LEFT(items.TextBody,77)}..."></apex:outputtext>                                          thank you so much for the quick suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

One way to easily substring a field is to use formula expressions

```
<apex:outputText value="{!LEFT(items.textbody,n)}/>
```

where  `n` is the number of characters you want. `n` could even be a merge field from the controller.

VF has access to almost the entire function library available in SFDC as seen [here in the VF doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm).